# Setting one overlay view on other

Tags: android, overlay

I came to know we can add overlay ovew on top of all other apps by this referencem,

[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

But I would like to know how to make secondly added view will be on top of first view when second view moved on top of first view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to the link you posted:

Views are placed on top of eachother at the order that you add them. Meaning the second view you add will be on top of the first. If you want to put the first on top of the second then you have to remove it and add it again.